# Aggregation Operation in Kettle / Pentaho

Tags: business-intelligence, etl, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to do an aggregate operation between some columns from an Excel file input. I have the following case:

```
Column 1   Column 2    Column 3

X            $15           A
X            $20           A
Y            $1        B
Y            $1        B
Y            $3        C
```

And i want to achieve this aggregation operation:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3

X             $35           A
Y             $2            B
Y             $3            C
```

As you see, the Column 1 and 3 are the criteria for doing the aggregation operation, in this case, i want to get the sum of the column 2.

Is there any way to do this in Pentaho Data Integration? I've tried with "Join Rows" and "Join Rows (As a cartesian product)", but, i have no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look to [Group By step](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Group+By). It should allow you to group by `Column 1` and `Column 3` and sum `Column 2`.